# C - fgets and fputs not editing file data

Tags: c, fgets, fseek, fputs

Full code: https://pastebin.com/NpspcJB8

I'm not sure if I'm using `fgets()` and `fputs()` correctly, but I need this or something similar in order to edit my file for the program. Within my program, I will have created a file, but when I generate the file contents in my program, I get this:

**File output**

```
Space: D44 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D45 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D46 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D47 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D48 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D49 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty

Space: D50 Customer Name: empty Registration number: empty
 empty
 empty
 empty
 empty
 empty
 empty
 empty
```

This happens when I add parking spaces in the program, and I believe that this merely shifts the array values. I need `empty` in the file output removed, which I attempted in a code using the functions I first mentioned, within a function I created:

```
int CheckExtraInput() {

    fptr=fopen("parking_spaces.txt", "r+");

    if (fptr==NULL) {
        printf("Error! File does not exist");
        return 1;
    }   

    char extraInput[] = " empty\n";

// http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ 

// https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm  

//  char *s = strchr(extraInput, '\n');
//  if(s) *s = '\0';

//  fseek(fptr, 7, SEEK_SET);
    while (fgets(extraInput, 8, fptr) != NULL) {

        fputs(" aaa ", fptr);

    }

}
```

I used `" aaa "` to test this code, to which it does not. I believe that I could use more in order to get this to work, but I'm not sure what; I used `fseek()` earlier on with similar results.

I just need to find out a way for the program to go to the end of the file, and if it starts to detect `empty`, it needs to remove it to save storage space.

Comment: `while (fgets(extraInput, 8, fptr) != NULL) {

        fputs(" aaa ", fptr);` is a problem as it attempts to read/write without an interviewing file position setting.  Suggest reading from one file and write to another.  Good editing does not destroy the original until the new copy is completely done.

Comment: Minor, suggest `fgets(extraInput, sizeof extraInput, fptr)`

Comment: @chux I think I'll need to uncomment `fseek()`, maybe; thanks for the suggestion, though, but i'm not sure about using two files yet.

Comment: The text file update model I use is "file + edits --> newfile" "rename file oldfile", "rename newfile file" "delete oldfile".  Note that any one of these steps may fail.  These steps reduce the chances of forever losing the data.